# How to re-pack *.class and lib/*.jar after extracting them?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I am a newbie in handling class files, jar, ... etc.

Usually, I just download a jar file and use it for running hadoop job.

Now, I need to do extract the contents from the jar and modify some files and re-pack them into a new jar.

I extracted files (*.class, lib/*.jar) from the jar file:

```
jar xf ./ABC.jar
```

Then, I have the extracted files in:

```
./ABC/*
```

I tried to recombine them together in this way:

```
jar cvf New_ABC.jar ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF libs/*.jar -C ABC .
```

When I use the New_ABC.jar for running hadoop job, I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.long.ClassNotFoundException: BLAH.blah
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass
   at ...
```

What's wrong in my procedure? How can I use the New_ABC.jar as if it's the same with ABC.jar?

Thanks, I appreciate your help

Below is the contents of the file ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Anonymous
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_66
```

Comment: missing *.class I would assume - but just look inside the JARs: `jar -tvf name.jar` (obviously using the correct names) - also not sure about your MANIFEST but I don't use hadoop

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The output prints the class name: BLAH.blah.class . :<

Comment: in the same directory structure